# static like behavior for a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to fill a dictionary after reading a bulky file. I have created a method to read file and fill this dictionary. This method is called in every iteration which is degrading the performance. Is there anyway through which I can just declare this dictionary as static and it remains throughout the lifetime of the application.

I tried to simulate this with the code below (using nonlocal) but doesn't help. The file is read in every iteration.

```
def read_data_from_file( path ):
    file_name = path + '.dat'

    common_array_dict = dict()

    def get_the_dict():
        try:
            common_array_list = list()
            nonlocal common_array_dict 

            if common_array_dict :
                return common_array_dict 

            with open(file_name, 'rb') as file:
                new_list = pickle.load(file)
            print("Reading file")
            for do_operations here:
                 <stat1>
                 <stat2>
        except IOError:
            print("Output file doesn't exist! Continuing..")
            return

    return get_the_dict
```

Any suggestions will be helpful :)

Comment: Easiest way would be to look up some [memoization decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) and decorate the function accordingly. Or just bind the result of that function to some (global) variable and use that variable instead of calling the function again. No need to use global within the function.

Comment: Did you mean to use a higher-order function here? Anyway, I don't understand why you don't just make the dictionary at the module level scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to look up some memoization decorator, e.g. from [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize), and decorate the function accordingly, then just use it normally in your code. Each file should be read only once and the result will be stored in a cache for later use.

```
@memoize
def read_data_from_file( path ):
    ...
```

---

Alternatively, just bind the result of that function to some (possibly global) variable and use that variable instead of calling the function again. No need to use global within the function itself.

```
data = read_data_from_file("the/path/to/the/file")
....
do_stuff_with(data) # use result from function
...
do_more_stuff(data) # don't call read_data_from_file again
```